# Split vector when a smaller number is found

Tags: r, vector, split

Let's say I have a vector

```
v <- c(2, 3, 5, 11, 3, 19, 20, 88, 20, 22)
```

I would like them split when a number is smaller than the number that preceded it in the vector e.g.

```
2, 3, 5, 11
3, 19, 20, 88
20, 22
```

I've tried several approaches but, being new to the language, I can't quite find a way. I tried substracting each element by the next and getting the index of negative numbers, which gave me the indices at which I should split the vector but I haven't found how to use `split()` to get the result from these indices. That was my most fruitful approach, though it seems inefficient.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one approach:

```
> split(v, cumsum(c(1, diff(v) < 0)))
$`1`
[1]  2  3  5 11

$`2`
[1]  3 19 20 88

$`3`
[1] 20 22
```

Conceptually, it's similar to what you hand in mind. `diff` takes care of subtracting each element by the next. `diff(v) < 0` creates a logical vector. `c(1, diff(v) < 0)` converts that to a vector of 1s and 0s, which we can use `cumusm` on to get our "groups" by which to split.

Comment: I could've sworn I had tried that exact line of code based on another answer but without success. Anyway, thank you very much.